# What vocabulary is useful for a person who wants to learn more about turning product ideas into product realities?

Tags: job-search, career-development

Ever since I was a child, I have had ideas for products. The products are usually for mechanical or electrical gadgets.

The description given above is a little too general, so I will offer an example. Today, I was in my kitchen when I realized that I did not know what today's' date  was. I decided that it would be useful to have a special type refrigerator magnet.

It could be a very big fridge magnet - rectangular in shape -- approximately 8 to 12 inches wide and at least 3 inches tall. It would be like a digital clock, except that it would display month and day, but not the time. The back would have 4 neodymium magnets in the corners, so that our refrigerator date display could be attached to the outside of your refrigerator door. IT would be battery operated. I would like to have a radio receiver listen to time broadcast out from one of the atomic clock centers hundreds of miles away. That way, the magnetic refrigerator date display could always have the correct date.

I pride myself of thinking-up realistic products which doable with today's technology. No star trek transporter beams are allowed.

The fridge-magnet date-display thing might not be the best idea, but I have hundreds of other gadgets I have thought up. Good ideas are a dime a dozen, but they have never made me any money for me.

In the ten years since I graduated from high school, the only real jobs I have had were doing manual labor in warehouses. It is quite depressing really. I have absolutely no idea how to turn my ideas into reality. How to turn your ideas into a reality was never brought up by any of my school teachers, or by my parents. In school, my peers and I were only taught how to memorize things, such as George Washington's birthday or the quadratic formula. My father's attitude has always been that someone else has the idea, and he simply implements it.

Currently, I need your help expanding my lexicon in order to do research. I want to move into an industry where we imagine and design products, but I don't speak the industry's language. What vocabulary words should I try sticking into Google? I am sure that, long before I was born, someone invented various words and phrases describe the product design process, but I don't know what those words and phrases are. I also have no idea what kind of background product designers usually have.

It is difficult to learn more if you don't know what words to type into your search bar.

Can you offer any vocabulary suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps just google "patent this" and "patent that", to see what's out there.

Comment: I think what you are referring to is similar to drafting a proposal and business plan.  As these reflect the business side of manufacturing and selling products, perhaps look into some business courses at your local college.  If it were software that you were creating, a course in Project Management might cover several of these concepts for that particular field.

Comment: @JanetPlanet mechanical and electrical gadgets in the question.

Comment: How many gadgets you actually created? You are absolutely right about "dime a dozen" saying.  You need to be able to *show* something and not just talk about it.

Answer (score 2):

It's called product design, it's a big field.

Ideally you have the engineering skills to actually make things or at least know if they're actually sensible. You can do it self-taught, but depending on the product that might not be feasible for some ideas.

Just selling ideas is called concept selling and is really a soft skill like marketing. Realistically an idea on it's own is worth as much as the marketing behind it.

Talking about wonderful ideas amongst an interested peer group is often done in bars but isn't great for generating revenue.

Comment: @Donald, Most Hollywood screenwriters know very little about the industries they portray in movies. The movie you're describing would be a horrible thing to watch for someone trying to learn about this field because it would most likely mislead them.

Comment: I think nowadays it has become easier than ever to come with prototypes on your own and try to turn it into a sellable product. 3D printing, things like arduino, internet resources and discussions, crowdfunding, ...  sure not everybody will eventually come to actual distribution of a product, but not so long ago the path to success was, I think, much longer...

Comment: @LaurentS. yeah, easier with a proof of concept prototype though I would think. Not sure how much funding you'd get if you stuck magnets and a radio antenna on a calendar.

Comment: @Kilisi I see that you do not like the idea of a large refrigerator magnet which display the current date. I do not think the magnets would interfere a small little radio which synchronizes the refrigerator clock's time with an atomic clock 200 miles away. For instance, I have a magnetic mount for my cellphone. The magnet does not fry the electronics inside of the phone. The magnet does not prevent the cellphone from sending and receiving phone calls on the traditional microwave bandwidths. My cellphone can send and receive wi-fi signals too.

Comment: @Kilisi The existence of cellphones prove the feasibility of an electronic device which sticks to your refrigerator door and displays the current date. In fact, you could use a cellphone for such a purpose, but it would be expensive and waste unnecessary electronics. my cellphone has a steel plate on the back which attaches to magnets. I could slap a neodymium magnet on the fridge. Then attach my cellphone to the fridge door. If I ran an app which displayed the current date, we would be done. I want lower battery usage, a lower price point (less than a days wages), and simpler inner workings

Comment: @Kilisi If you do not like the idea of a refrigerator date display, I have other product concepts. For example, I helped my father renovate part of his house. Running wires from a wall switch to a ceiling light is very difficult when most of the wall has been covered in plaster-board. The 2x4s and inside of the wall are not exposed. As such, a wireless light switch would be nice.

Comment: @Kilisi a wireless light-switch would use the same underlying technology as remote controls used to open and close garage doors on a house. Inside of suburban garages, there device which controls the electric motor to raise or lower the garage door. The door controller would instead be wired to turn on and off a ceiling light. No matter what, you have to wire the ceiling light to power, and you would wire that power to the door controller box and stuff the garage door controller in the ceiling.

Comment: @Kilisi  Many people have a remote control for a garage door attached to the sun visor in their car. If you put the guts of the  garage door remote from your sun visor inside of something which looks like a light-switch, you would then have lightswtich which requires less wiring than traditional light-switches, relatively speaking.

Comment: any idea is as good as the marketing behind it, doesn't even have to be a good idea to make money. Can you actually make any of these gadgets? It's a lot easier to sell an idea if you have a prototype.